# MySQLでlocalhostで接続できるが127.0.0.1で接続できない

Tags: mysql

`mysql -uroot -p`
とすれば`root@localhost`になり接続はできるが

`mysql -uroot -p -h 127.0.0.1`
とすると
`Access denied for user 'root'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES)`
となり接続できない

やりたいことはSeaquelProからsqlに接続です

Comment: localhostでいいのでログインして`SELECT Host,User FROM mysql.user WHERE \`User\`='root';`で`127.0.0.1`は出ますか？

Answer (score 2):

mysqlでは、「user名@ホスト名」を1つの単位として権限やパスワードを設定します。
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/account-names.html

また、localhostと127.0.0.1は、mysqlでは別扱いで、挙動も厳密には異なります。
（localhostの場合はソケット通信になる）
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/can-not-connect-to-server.html

つまり
root@localhostのみにパスワードや権限が設定がされていた場合、
root@127.0.0.1は定義されていない状態になります。